# Converting a string to int in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a `String` that represents an integer value and would like to convert it to an `int`. Is there a groovy equivalent of Java's `Integer.parseInt(String)`?

Comment: why not just use the def keyword?

Comment: I have a string parameter that contains an integer. Using def i = string_parameter results in class cast exception if I later use i as an int.

Answer (score 569, accepted):

Use the `toInteger()` method to convert a `String` to an `Integer`, e.g.

```
int value = "99".toInteger()
```

An alternative, which avoids using a deprecated method (see below) is

```
int value = "66" as Integer
```

If you need to check whether the `String` *can* be converted before performing the conversion, use

```
String number = "66"

if (number.isInteger()) {
  int value = number as Integer
}
```

### Deprecation Update

In recent versions of Groovy one of the  `toInteger()` methods has been deprecated. The following is taken from `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StringGroovyMethods` in Groovy 2.4.4

```
/**
 * Parse a CharSequence into an Integer
 *
 * @param self a CharSequence
 * @return an Integer
 * @since 1.8.2
 */
public static Integer toInteger(CharSequence self) {
    return Integer.valueOf(self.toString().trim());
}

/**
 * @deprecated Use the CharSequence version
 * @see #toInteger(CharSequence)
 */
@Deprecated
public static Integer toInteger(String self) {
    return toInteger((CharSequence) self);
}
```

You can force the non-deprecated version of the method to be called using something awful like:

```
int num = ((CharSequence) "66").toInteger()
```

Personally, I much prefer:

```
int num = 66 as Integer
```

Comment: Caveat emptor: you need to check the value with `isInteger()` first, because `toInteger()` will throw an exception if the string is not numeric. Same applies to `toFloat()`/`isFloat()`

Comment: In the [2.1.6 api documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html) isInteger/toInteger are deprecated. What is the current best way to do this then?

Comment: Using Integer paramValue = params.int('paramName') isn't null safe though. If there is no param with the name "paramName" in the param map you get an exception about can't cast null to int.

Comment: In Grails, I type my controller action parameters, e.g. `def displayInvoice(Integer accountNumber, String accountType)`. Any binding errors will show up in the errors object and the parameter will be assigned the default value. See the docs for data binding. I believe this comes directly from Spring MVC.

Comment: just wanted to add, that since Groovy 1.8 `int` is indeed `int`. Groovy will still display the Integer class, because of boxing, but you will for example not be able to assign `null` to an `int`, which was possible in 1.0. We considered the change being non-critical, since you already could not use null as argument for a method call parameter of type `int`. This is all still different from Java, as in Java you cannot convert Integer to Long by a simple assignment or call an int taking method with a Long.

Comment: I just keep getting `No such property: isInteger for class: java.lang.String. Stacktrace follows[...]`

Comment: @pakman `StringGroovyMethods.isInteger(String)` and `DefaultGroovyMethods.isInteger(CharSequence)` are deprecated in favor of [`StringGroovyMethods.isInteger(CharSequence)`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/StringGroovyMethods.html#isInteger(java.lang.CharSequence)). Same goes for `toInteger()`.

Comment: @Hugo sounds like you're leaving off the parentheses. `'99'.isInteger()`, not `'99'.isInteger`.

Answer (score 75):

Several ways to do it, this one's my favorite:

```
def number = '123' as int
```

Comment: Same problem as above, this will throw an exception if the string is not a number. Check with `isInteger()` first.

Comment: @ank the question asked for an equivalent of `Integer.parseInt(String)` which also throws an Exception if the string is not a number, so given the question, I don't consider this a "problem"

Comment: I believe this is the way Groovy intends it to be done.  You can generally use 'as' as a type conversion for anything (Sometimes you may have to attach a converter method, like if you really want to do JFrame as Boolean or something crazy like that.

Answer (score 32):

As an addendum to [Don's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1716699/363701), not only does groovy add a `.toInteger()` method to `String`s, it also adds `toBigDecimal()`, `toBigInteger()`, `toBoolean()`, `toCharacter()`, `toDouble()`, `toFloat()`, `toList()`, and `toLong()`.

In the same vein, groovy also adds `is*` eqivalents to all of those that return `true` if the `String` in question can be parsed into the format in question.

The relevant GDK page [is here.](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Number.html)

Comment: This is the correct answer - check first with `isInteger()`, then do `toInteger()`... that is, unless you'd rather add a `try`/`catch` block :) but using exceptions for this is a bad idea.

Comment: @anktastic I'd argue that my answer is more correct because the question asked for "a groovy equivalent of Java's Integer.parseInt(String)", i.e. an unchecked conversion

Answer (score 27):

I'm not sure if it was introduced in recent versions of groovy (initial answer is fairly old), but now you can use:

```
def num = mystring?.isInteger() ? mystring.toInteger() : null
```

or

```
def num = mystring?.isFloat() ? mystring.toFloat() : null
```

I recommend using floats or even doubles instead of integers in the case if the provided string is unreliable.

Comment: +1 best solution IMO as it includes null check in addition to type check before conversion

Comment: I recommend against using floats or doubles because they are inherently inaccurate. As Groovy makes using BigDecimals as easy as any other Number, if you need more accuracy than an Integer, use that. Secondly, this approach seems safe, but the result can be that num == null, so you need to be careful with that

Comment: For the first sample code, I guess you wanted to write `mystring.toInteger()` instead of `mystring.toFloat()`. So `def num = mystring?.isInteger() ? mystring.toInteger() : null` would be correct.

Answer (score 18):

Well, Groovy accepts the Java form just fine. If you are asking if there is a *Groovier* way, there is a way to go to `Integer`.

Both are shown here:

```
String s = "99"
assert 99 == Integer.parseInt(s)
Integer i = s as Integer
assert 99 == i
```

Comment: This answer also throws when the string is not numeric - watch out!

Answer (score 7):

also you can make static import

```
import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt as asInteger
```

and after this use

```
String s = "99"
asInteger(s)
```

Comment: Neat, I forget about the small things a lot.

Answer (score 3):

`toInteger()` method is available in groovy, you could use that.

Answer (score 2):

Several ways to achieve this. Examples are as below

```
a. return "22".toInteger()
b. if("22".isInteger()) return "22".toInteger()
c. return "22" as Integer()
d. return Integer.parseInt("22")
```

Hope this helps

Comment: How is this adding anything to the question not already present in the 8 existing answers?

Comment: My bad, got a bit greedy here

Answer (score 1):

Groovy Style conversion:

```
Integer num = '589' as Integer
```

If you have request parameter:

```
Integer age = params.int('age')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def str = "32"

int num = str as Integer
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the an other way. if you don't like exceptions.

```
def strnumber = "100"
def intValue = strnumber.isInteger() ?  (strnumber as int) : null
```

Comment: I think this is the same answer as [#16877253](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16877253/699665) by [@Shmaperator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2444035/shmaperator)

Answer (score 0):

The way to use should still be the `toInteger()`, because it is not really deprecated.

```
int value = '99'.toInteger()
```

The String version is deprecated, but the `CharSequence` is an Interface that a String implements. So, using a String is ok, because your code will still works even when the method will only work with `CharSequence`. Same goes for `isInteger()`

See this question for reference :
[How to convert a String to CharSequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391970/how-to-convert-a-string-to-charsequence)

I commented, because the notion of deprecated on this method got me confuse and I want to avoid that for other people.

Answer (score -1):

The Simpler Way Of Converting A String To Integer In Groovy Is As Follows...

```
String aa="25"
int i= aa.toInteger()
```

Now "i" Holds The Integer Value.

Comment: What does this add to existing answers? The accepted answer posted 9 years ago starts with: "Use the `toInteger()` method to conver...