# groovy loop does not stop

Tags: groovy, soapui

this is part of a teardown script, but it is giving me some trouble.

```
while ( n-- > 0 ) {
    testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue( "ExpectedNo" + n, "")
}
```

n starts with value 5 and does reset ExpectedNo0 through ExpectedNo4 to blank as it is supposed to do, but afterwards it sets up 46 more property entries as follows
ExpectedNo/
ExpectedNo.
ExpectedNo,
....

I am not sure what to make of this as I am not very versed in groovy.. any help would be appreaciated!

Comment: sure it's not a problem somewhere else in your code?

Comment: What I mean is, that loop stops fine

Comment: i only have 2 loops (setup, teardown) in 2 different steps. I can see it setting up ok, but the above teardown script does too much :)

Comment: The loop works though...  You could try a different way round, ie: `5.times { testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue( "ExpectedNo$it", "" )  }` or `for( n=0 ; n < 5 ; n++ ) { testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue( "ExpectedNo$n", "" ) }` but as I don't think the loop is to blame, my guess is you'll see the same result...

Comment: I set it to removeProperty, which works fine. Its not optimal but whatever works, right? thx for your time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To understand the source of your problem, take a look at ASCII table ([link to a one](http://www.asciitable.com/)). You'll see that before characters '0'-'5' there stands (in reverse order) '/', '.', '-', etc. Groovy interprets your `n` as character instead of integer variable. All you need is to convert `n` from String to Integer. See the next SO question how to do this: [Groovy String to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713481/groovy-string-to-int).

Comment: Why does this not occur with `while ( n-- > 0 ) { println "ExpectedNo" + n }`?

Comment: n is assigned a property value beforehand, which is taken from a database table.

Comment: Ahhh, I see.  Yeah `char n = '5' ; while ( n-- > 0 ) { println "ExpectedNo" + n }` would cause this...

Comment: Also happens with `for (i in 1..n)`, `for (i=1;i<n;i++)` and so on. +1 for the response!