# How to convert String to int in Groovy the right way

Tags: groovy

First of all, I am aware of question '[Groovy String to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713481/groovy-string-to-int)' and it's responses. I am a newbe to Groovy language and right now playing around some basics. The most straightforward ways to convert String to int seem to be:

```
int value = "99".toInteger()
```

or:

```
int value = Integer.parseInt("99")
```

These both work, but comments to these answers got me confused. The first method

```
String.toInteger()
```

is deprecated, as stated in groovy documentation. I also assume that

```
Integer.parseInt()
```

makes use of the core Java feature.

So my question is: is there any *legal, pure groovy* way to perform such a simple task as converting String to an int?

Comment: `String.toInteger` isn't deprecated, it was just moved to `CharSequence` (a String is a CharSequence)

Comment: Thanks @tim_yates, but according to http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#toInteger(java.lang.CharSequence) I think that CharSequence version is also deprecated. However, I now see that version for java.lang.Number isn't deprecated, but it is now clear to me when my String become a Number...

Comment: Yeah, that's the internal docs.  That method's deprecated, as it moved to a dfferent class...  The interface docs are here: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/CharSequence.html#toInteger()

Comment: Ah, and it makes sense now :) So my worries about the clarity or purity were unnecessary, thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I might be wrong, but I think *most Grooviest* way would be using a safe cast `"123" as int`.

Really you have a lot of ways with slightly different behaviour, and all are correct.

```
"100" as Integer // can throw NumberFormatException
"100" as int // throws error when string is null. can throw NumberFormatException
"10".toInteger() // can throw NumberFormatException and NullPointerException
Integer.parseInt("10") // can throw NumberFormatException (for null too)
```

If you want to get null instead of exception, use recipe from answer you have linked.

```
def toIntOrNull = { it?.isInteger() ? it.toInteger() : null }
assert 100 == toIntOrNull("100")
assert null == toIntOrNull(null)
assert null == toIntOrNull("abcd")
```

Comment: @koto Congratulations with successful start on StackOverflow! =)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a String which is a **math expression**, not just a single number, try [groovy.lang.Script.evaluate(String expression)](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Script.html#evaluate%28java.lang.String%29):

```
print evaluate("1+1"); // note that evalute can throw CompilationFailedException
```

Comment: That seems a bit offtopic, as OP asked about Simple way to convert String to int.

Evaluate of any kind opens a whole lot of security problems.

Moreover, Script#evaluate is not recommended way to do what you suggest, but [groovy.util.Eval](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/Eval.html) is.