# How to use Jenkins local defined variable in IF statement?

Tags: jenkins

I have below code

```
def result = readFile('res.txt')
echo "${result}"

if ("${result}" > 5 )

{ 
        echo "Yes"
    } else {
        echo "No"
    } 
}
```

It is printing NO but the answer in `${result}` -> 11 which means it should print Yes. Can u pls help.

Comment: Did you try "${result}".toInteger() > 5? My guess is you compare a String with an Integer.

Comment: `readFile()` always returns a string, but you actually want a number, so you have to convert string to number. [`Integer.parseInt()` is your friend](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_parseint.htm).

Comment: Yeah ${result}".toInteger() > 5 works for me. Thank you so much. I need to add try catch also here so that the IF statement will fail then it will stop the build and does not go to next stage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert String to int in Groovy the right way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36007867/how-to-convert-string-to-int-in-groovy-the-right-way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in comments - you should cast the result to integer. Both `result.toInteger()` and `Integer.parseInt(result)` will work, although the first one is more straightforward and doesn't complain about extra white space (e.g. trailing endline character).

Besides, you don't need to mess with strange constructs like `"${result}"` because `result` is a normal variable, so your code may look like this:

```java
def result = readFile('res.txt')
echo "${result}"

if (result.toInteger() > 5 ) { 
    echo "Yes"
} else {
    echo "No"
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me.. am getting "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:  error

Comment: Then maybe your result does not parse to integer.