# User defined variable displayed as 48 and not 0

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I created a user defined variable `i` and put value 0.
In groovy I try to run on a list starting [i], but it returned 48.
when I hard coded put 0, the script is OK
why I is set to 48?

```
List<String> myList = props.get("myListKey");
int i = vars.get("i"); 
String id = myList[i];
//String id = myList[0];
System.out.println("id:  " + id);
vars.putObject("id", id);
System.out.println("I is:  " + i);
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is the value of myList ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to convert String to number in groovy is using `toInteger()` function:

```
int value =  vars.get("i").toInteger()    
log.info("I2 is:  " + value);
```

Currently you return the ASCII value of character `0` (48). you can check also [other options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713481/groovy-string-to-int) to convert String to int.