# jenkinsfile parameter name resolution at run time

Tags: jenkins, parameters, jenkins-pipeline

I have below stage in jenkinsfile where the param name is derived from for loop "i" value:
How to interpolate at run time the parameter value derived at run time

```
stage ('Create new part'){
          steps {
             script{
                 sh "mkdir ${WORKSPACE}/inventories && touch ${WORKSPACE}/inventories/hosts"
                  for (i in (["db", "pr", "pl", "ad", "lo", "log", "jm", "se", "fo", "me", "he"]) ) {
                       if ("${params."'$i'_instances"}" == "3" && "${params."'$i'_disksize"}" > "80") {
                          sh "echo 'Entered if loop'" 
                          sh "echo '['$i'-servers]'>> ${WORKSPACE}/inventories/hosts"
                          for (j=1; j<=params.$i_instances; j++) {
                              sh "echo '${params.project_name}-${params.environment_name}-${$i_prefix}-$j target_fs="${params.$i_FS_TYPE}" percentage_fs="{params.$i_fs_percentage}"' >> ${WORKSPACE}/inventories/hosts"
                            }
                         }   
                   }
                }
            }
          }
```

Comment: What’s the error that you see? Why not simply use `if (params."${i}_instances" == "3"...`? Single quotes around `i` will prevent interpolation.

Comment: @DibakarAditya I get this error ```groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: i_instances for class: WorkflowScript``` for line ```if (params."${i_instances}" == "3" && params."${i_disksize}" != "80")```

Comment: Close the curly braces after `i`.

Comment: @DibakarAditya . Thanks a lot, it works :) How can I convert param value to int to use > 0r < operator?

Comment: You can use the `string.toInteger()` method. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713481/groovy-string-to-int.

Comment: @DibakarAditya Thanks a lot, I appreciate. I get through that stage but get error for ```                             sh "echo '${params.project_name}-${params.environment_name}-env."${i}_prefix"-${j} target_fs='params."${i}_FS_TYPE"' percentage_fs='params."${i}_fs_percentage"'' >> ${WORKSPACE}/inventories/hosts"
``` and error is ```/var/jenkins/workspace/disk@tmp/durable-f2d29cc8/script.sh: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201974/discussion-between-user312307-and-dibakar-aditya).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single quotes around Groovy GStrings prevent interpolation. Use `if (params."${i}_instances" == "3" && params."${i}_disksize" != "80")` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your input, how can I print this in echo ```target_fs = ${params."${i}_FS_TYPE"}```

Comment: @user312307 In this case `println` is better suited than `echo` as in `println("target_fs = " + params."${i}_FS_TYPE")`.

Comment: I used echo to print this in a file on my server, will println also do that?