# Gradle Task showing error when executing in the gradle build

Tags: java, gradle

The error that i am facing is the `class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.String`. when running `gradle test -Pnum=10`.
This is my code:

```
     def fibo(n){
 //something
        }
    }
        task test() {
           doLast {
               fibo num
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

When entering the value of `num` using the parameter `-Pnum=10`, `num` will be a `String`, but you need an `Integer`.

Changing the task `test` like this should fix it:

```
task test() {
   doLast { 
       fibo num.toInteger()
   }
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1716699/8178842) for more information about converting a `String` to an `Integer` in Groovy.

Answer (score 0):

Cast you argument to integer before using, as its passed as string
`int nValue = Integer.valueOf(n);`