# Jenkins: hudson.AbortException: Invalid instance plan CPU value for TEST

Tags: jenkins, groovy, operators

Jenkins 2.277.2
I am not that experienced with groovy and groovy operators but
not sure whats wrong with the logic...

Getting this error:

Instance plan is dashDBStandard Cores are 4 and RAM is 16

...

hudson.AbortException: Invalid instance plan CPU value for TEST

```
'''
    print "Instance plan is ${db2instance_plan} Cores are ${cores} and RAM is ${ram}"
                            if ((db2instance_plan == 'dashDBStandard') && (cores > '16')) {
                               error "Invalid instance plan CPU value for TEST"
                            }
                            if ((db2instance_plan == 'dashDBStandard') && (ram > '64')) {
                               error "Invalid instance plan RAM value for TEST"
                            }
                            if ((db2instance_plan == 'dashDBNebula') && (cores < '4' )) {
                               error "Invalid instance plan CPU value for PROD"
                            }
                            if ((db2instance_plan == 'dashDBNebula') && (ram < '16' )) {
                               error "Invlaid instance plan RAM for PROD"
                            }

'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error keyword in Jenkins pipelines just throws an `hudson.AbortException` with the specified message (stops the execution).

But it looks like you are treating `cores` and `ram` parameters as strings, and therefore the `>` operator will compare strings and not numbers as you probably intended.

If you input parameters are integers just use the following:

```
if ((db2instance_plan == 'dashDBStandard') && (cores > 16)) {
```

Otherwise if the input is a string you can convert it to a number:

```
if ((db2instance_plan == 'dashDBStandard') && (cores.toInteger() > 16)) {
```

See [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713481/converting-a-string-to-int-in-groovy) for other ways to convert string to number