# string to charsequence

Tags: android, string, charsequence

Can somebody please show me a bit of code to convert a string to charsequence?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[String implements the Interface CharSequence](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), so String **is a** CharSequence.

And you may never instantiate interfaces. Wherever CharSequence is required, String will fit.

Comment: so a straightforward cast will work? ie Charsequence cs = (Charsequence) String str;

Comment: No cast is needed, and you can't cast anyway. String is a CharSequence.

Comment: This (for example) is a valid assignment: `CharSequence cs = new String("hello");`

Comment: Let me get this right - I can use string and charsequence interchangeably with no modifications, casting or whatever? Like, String str="abc"; Charsequence cs; cs = str; and vice versa?

Comment: No. the first side is true, but its inheritance, which is one-way. "Every Drug Dealer is a criminal, but not every criminal is a drug dealer" :) more seriously, read the java tutorial about interfaces, it worth reading: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html

Comment: The actual bit of code I am using right now is EditText, which requires a charsequence. If I use a string... editBox.setText(str); that's OK?

Comment: Note that CharSequence cs = new String("hello");  is *not* necessary - one only needs CharSequence cs = "hello"; You should avoid calling the String(String) constructor in almost all cases - it wastes resources and is very rarely needed (only if you really want two different instances)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
// final CharSequence cs = mEditText.getText();    
final CharSequence cs = "Hi how are u";

String[] vals = cs.toString().split(" ");

for(int i=0;i<vals.length;i++) {
    System.out.println("args values...."+i+""+vals[i].toString());          
}
```

Comment: string to charsequence, not charsequence to string

Comment: final CharSequence cs = "ur String";
System.out.println(cs);

Answer (score 2):

As [MByD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5817580/593709) pointed, `String` implements `CharSequence`, so its already a `CharSequence`. But if you want to convert `CharSequence` to `String`, Here is the code:

```
CharSequence cs = "string";
String s = cs.toString();
foo(s); // prints "string"

public void foo(CharSequence cs) { 
  System.out.println(cs);
}
```

The SO thread can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391970/how-to-convert-string-to-charsequence-in-java)

Comment: string to charsequence, not charsequence to string

Comment: But "string" is a String. and that thread was asked the same as you asked. A simple google by copying your title gave me [Thread](http://www.google.com.pk/search?q=string+to+charsequence%3F&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=8D5&rls=org.mozilla:en-US%3Aofficial&source=hp&q=string+to+charsequence&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=dfdcd119b0bef06c&biw=1280&bih=558)