# Choosing between CharSequence and String for an API

Tags: java, string, charsequence

[A `String` **is-a** `CharSequence`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391970/how-to-convert-a-string-to-charsequence-in-java). Many methods in the Java library accept `CharSequence` so [they operate more generally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049228/charsequence-vs-string-in-java). Some classe have a `String` method (for example, `Writer.write(String)`) and also implement `Appendable` with an equivalent `CharSequence` method (for example, `Writer.append(CharSequence)`).

If I am writing a class that delegates to such a class, ands needs some text input, I can choose for that input to be a `String` or a `CharSequence`. Choosing the later makes the class more flexible, by giving the client more options. But I don't see much code that does so: text arguments are almost invariably a `String` rather than a `CharSequence`. Is there a down-side to using `CharSequence`? Is there a performance hit? Or is it just programmer intertia or ignorance that causes use of `String` rather than `CharSequence`?

Compare

```
class XMLWriter {
   private final Writer writer;

   // more stuff here

   public void writeComment(String text) {
      writer.write("<!-- ");
      writer.write(text);
      writer.write(" -->");
   }
}
```

with

```
class XMLWriter {
   private final Writer writer;

   // more stuff here

   public void writeComment(CharSequence text) {
      writer.write("<!-- ");
      writer.append(text);
      writer.write(" -->");
   }
}
```

Comment: Your logic makes a lot of sense to me. By using CharSequence you would allow calling code to supply a StringBuffer/StringBuilder without needing to invoke toString() on it -- which happens a lot.

Comment: @Andy yes, I had `StringBuilder` in mind when I wrote the question.

Comment: See this Question’s later duplicate, [When to use CharSequence in an API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13234584/642706).

Comment: For more discussion, see also the Question, [CharSequence VS String in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1049228/642706), and its duplicate, [Exact difference between CharSequence and String](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11323962/642706) in java. And [my class diagram](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PIFk9.png).

Comment: Closed as a duplicate of the newer question, since that question attracted some thorough answers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Quoting [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/CharSequence.html) Javadoc:

> This interface does not refine the general contracts of the [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) and [`hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) methods. The result of testing two objects that implement `CharSequence` for equality is therefore, in general, undefined. Each object may be implemented by a different class, and there is no guarantee that each class will be capable of testing its instances for equality with those of the other. It is therefore inappropriate to use arbitrary `CharSequence` instances as elements in a set or as keys in a map.

Hence IMO We must think twice before using CharSequnce as a replacement for String.

Comment: Would you say that methods that merely output text, such as my example, should use `CharSequence` rather than `String`?

Comment: Good Answer, thanks for quoting the Javadoc. But I disagree with your conclusion. The concern about using the `CharSequence` returned by some API belongs to the *calling programmer* rather than the author of the API. If the calling programmer goes off to use the resulting text for a purpose such as a key in a map or adding to a set, they should should be the one to think twice. And then they should simply call [`CharSequence::toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/CharSequence.html#toString()). The author of an API should not worry about misuse later.