# Java: How to print corresponding alphabets till a number entered by user?

Tags: java, methods

I'm a beginner in Java and I'm trying to find out how to create a segment of code that can allow a user to enter a number between 1 and 26, and have the corresponding number of sequential letters to appear?

For example, if the user enters 3 then the computer would output a, b, c

Thank you in advance.

Update:
I wrote the following code but there is an error message stating that the i in the integer conversion part is a duplicate of a local variable?

In another method, the user inputs the number between 1 and 26 and I'm reading that input as the String variable "num".

```js
public String getChar (int i){
  String num;  
  String text = mini1Num.getText();
  
  Integer i = Integer.valueOf(text);

  return i > 0 && i < 27 ? String.valueOf((char)(i + 'A' - 1)) : null;


 }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting number to letter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813154/converting-number-to-letter)

Comment: Try a String array and a loop, then get back to us with some code.

Comment: it should be between 1-26 not 0-26

Comment: So.. Ascii or n-1, what is easiest for a beginner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int n <---- number entered by user
for(int i=97;i<(97+n);i++)
    System.out.print((char)i+" ");
```

This gives you what you need.

---

**EDIT**
The error in your code lies in the return statement.

```
return i > 0 && i < 27 ? String.valueOf((char)(i + 'A' - 1)) : null;
```

The value of **(i + 'A' -1)** is of type **char**. So the type casting basically takes the form of **(char) char** instead of **(char) int**, which is problematic.