# How do I convert number to a letter in Java?

Tags: java, string, numbers, converters

I want to make a program to convert number to letter, from 0-9 to ABCDEFGHIK.
For example: 
with n = 10 the output would be BA as 0 is A is 0 and B is 1.
Here is my code:

```
String convertNumber(long n) {
    String result="";
    String strN = Long.toString(n);
    for (int i=0; i < strN.length();i++){
        char ch = strN.charAt(i);
        switch(ch){
            case '0':
            result = "A";
            case '1':
            result = "B";
            case '2':
            result = "C";
            case '3':
            result = "D";
            case '4':
            result = "E";
            case '5':
            result = "F";
            case '6':
            result = "G";
            case '7':
            result = "H";
            case '8':
            result = "I";
            case '9':
            result = "K";
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

However, the results returns only K. Where did I do wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a number to a letter in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813154/how-do-i-convert-a-number-to-a-letter-in-java)

Comment: You need to break after each case or you will 'fall through' to the next case.  In your swtich, there are no breaks so it will always fall through to the last case.

Comment: Should `10` be `AB` or `BA`?

Comment: @sc0der oh yeaaa, sorry. My bad right there!

Comment: Ok, check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three mistakes in your program:

1. Not using `break` with the `case` and therefore every `case` will fall to the last `case`.
2. Using `=` instead of `+=`
3. Using the loop in reverse order than the required order. It should be `for (int i = strN.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)` instead of `for (int i=0; i < strN.length();i++)`

Given below is your corrected program:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(convertNumber(10));
    }

    static String convertNumber(long n) {
        String result = "";
        String strN = Long.toString(n);
        for (int i = strN.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            char ch = strN.charAt(i);
            switch (ch) {
            case '0':
                result += "A";
                break;
            case '1':
                result += "B";
                break;
            case '2':
                result += "C";
                break;
            case '3':
                result += "D";
                break;
            case '4':
                result += "E";
                break;
            case '5':
                result += "F";
                break;
            case '6':
                result += "G";
                break;
            case '7':
                result += "H";
                break;
            case '8':
                result = "I";
                break;
            case '9':
                result = "K";
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
AB
```

Comment: Gosh thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one:

```
static String convertNumber(int n) {
        int reminder;
        char[] arr = "ABCDEFGHIK".toCharArray();
        int len = arr.length;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        while (n != 0) {
            reminder = (int) n % 10;
            n /= 10;
            builder.append(arr[(reminder % len)]);
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
```

, main

```
  static public void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(convertNumber(65));
        System.out.println(convertNumber(78));
        System.out.println(convertNumber(99));
        System.out.println(convertNumber(901));
  }
```

, output

```
FG
IH
KK
BAK
```

Comment: Thank you for helping! I would have time to check my code xD Luv u

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: actually i just have a check in your code. It seems like 6,7,8,9 has the wrong letter.

Comment: because you mentioned in your post that the characters in `ABCDEFJIK` I have updated to `ABCDEFGHIK`

Comment: oh its mine that wrong, oops mb....

Comment: No problem, just figure out what' s the problem :D

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the break. add `break;` in every case, like this:

`case '0':
   result = "A";
   break;
 case '1':
   result = "B";
   break;`