# Scala: join an iterable of strings

Tags: string, scala

How do I "join" an iterable of strings by another string in Scala?

```
val thestrings = Array("a","b","c")
val joined = ???
println(joined)
```

I want this code to output `a,b,c` (join the elements by ",").

Comment: @scala_newbie I think your question was downvoted, 'cause some people think it lacks of research effort.

Comment: googling this question *is* my research effort

Comment: I saw this question while Googling 

Answer (score 509, accepted):

How about [mkString](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.7.5/scala/Iterable.html#mkString%28String%29) ?

```
theStrings.mkString(",")
```

A variant exists in which you can specify a prefix and suffix too.

See [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20171015150340/http://langref.org/scala/lists/output/join-the-elements-of-a-list-separated-by-commas) for an implementation using [foldLeft](http://oldfashionedsoftware.com/2009/07/10/scala-code-review-foldleft-and-foldright/), which is much more verbose, but perhaps worth looking at for education's sake.

Comment: Note that the foldLeft implementation assumes a non-empty list

Comment: Thanks! In case anyone wants to enclose string elements in quotes, mkString is also helpful: theStrings.mkString("'", "','", "'")

Comment: @Frawr That page links to a bunch of examples https://oldfashionedsoftware.com/2009/07/30/lots-and-lots-of-foldleft-examples/ which includes an implementation that uses pattern matching for the empty list (Nil) case. Modifying it to mimic mkString would be like this:  `def mkFoldLeftString[A](list:List[String], delim:String = ","): String = list match {
    case head :: tail => tail.foldLeft(head)(_ + delim + _)
    case Nil => ""
}`

Comment: The langref.org link is dead