# convert a list of String to a string

Tags: scala, list

I have the following list in input and :

```
val list=List("aimee,Paris,10",
"alex,Nice,12",
"Sara,Paris,15")
```

and I want to have a multiline String as output with the following format:

```
val output:String="aimee Paris,
alex Nice,
Sara Paris")
```

I wrote the following code

```
def listToMultLine (input:List[String]):String ={
input.map(_.split(",")).map(x => List(x(0),x(1)).mkString(","))
}
```

but this gives me erronous output
thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala: join an iterable of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13529512/scala-join-an-iterable-of-strings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the very mighty `foldLeft()`, check out this [blog](https://dzone.com/articles/secret-powers-foldleft-scala) to know more

```
 scala> list.map{
     | word => word.split(",").take(2)
     | }.foldLeft("")((complete, current)=>complete + current(0)+ ","+ current(1)+",\n")
```

You will get the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

`.mkString` is the solution for you which would concat all the elements in a collection to a String.

But looking at your output suggests that you want to remove the last digit and want each element in next line of the string.

So following should get you your desired output

```
scala> list.map(x => x.substring(0, x.lastIndexOf(","))).mkString(", \n")
res0: String =
aimee,Paris,
alex,Nice,
Sara,Paris
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to omit the last digit, so I would to suggest to use this solution, which is more readable than Ramesh's similar solution thanks to pattern-matching:

```
list.map(s => {
  val Seq(name,city,age) = s.split(',')
  (name,city)
}).mkString(", \n")
```

or alternatively

```
list.map(s => s.split(','))
  .map{case Seq(name,city,age) => (name,city)}
  .mkString(", \n")

res0: String = (aimee,Paris), 
(alex,Nice), 
(Sara,Paris)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
list.map(_.split(",")).map{case Array(a,b,c)=>a+" "+b}.mkString(",\n")
```

### In SCALA REPL:

```
scala> val list=List("aimee,Paris,10", "alex,Nice,12", "Sara,Paris,15")
list: List[String] = List(aimee,Paris,10, alex,Nice,12, Sara,Paris,15)

scala> list.map(_.split(",")).map{case Array(a,b,c)=>a+" "+b}.mkString(",\n")
res62: String =
aimee Paris,
alex Nice,
Sara Paris

scala>
```