# Android - The method is undefined

Tags: android, arrays, charsequence

I keep getting this error while trying to convert to CharSequence[].

The method toArray(CharSequence[]) is undefined for the type String

This is my code

```
              CharSequence[] cs = abbrev.toArray(new CharSequence[abbrev.length()]);
```

The abbrev is just splitting sentences into its first characters 
(Hello World --> HW)

```
       String[] result = matches.toString().split("\\s+");
        // The string we'll create

        String abbrev = "";

           // Loop over the results from the string splitting
           for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++){

               // Grab the first character of this entry
               char c = result[i].charAt(0);

               // If its a number, add the whole number
               if (c >= '0' && c <= '9'){
                   abbrev += result[i];
               }

               // If its not a number, just append the character
               else{
                   abbrev += c;
               }
           }
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What do you not understand about the very clear error message?

Answer (score 0):

Because `abbrev` is a string, you can't call `toArray` on it. Convert it to a `CharSequence` first.
For example,

```
CharSequence[] abbrevCs = abbrev; // it's converted automatically
CharSequence[] cs = abbrevCs.toArray(new CharSequence[abbrev.length()]);
```

Comment: He is trying to convert it to a CS

Comment: Tried that and getting this error

Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to CharSequence[]

Comment: Are all your tools up-to-date? Try rebuilding the project. If you're using an IDE, restart the IDE. Uninstall and reinstall things in a worst-case scenario. Have fun :)

Comment: Done all that still occurring

Comment: You uninstalled the JDK and the IDE? (and then reinstalled them?) If so, try it on a different computer....

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to convert a `String` to a `CharSequence` because a `String` **is** a `CharSequence`. You can just assign a `String` object to a `CharSequence` object and the conversion is implicit. See here for more details: [How to convert a String to CharSequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391970/how-to-convert-a-string-to-charsequence)

Comment: However, the OP is still getting the error message, so something's going wrong....

Comment: Right, but what the OP is doing isn't necessary or correct. They can simply assign the `abbrev` to `cs` and the conversion is implicit.

Comment: Of course, but _something's_ going wrong, so this solution won't work. If this answer was correct, the question wouldn't be here....