# Using Arraylist to display some of its data to Android setMultiChoiceItems(Alert Dialog)

Tags: java, android

I have a JSON file that stored in ArrayList using 
`public static ArrayList<UserData> userDataList = new ArrayList<>();` 
I also have a class namely as UserData to store multi data in it. Here is the code:

```
private String sid;
private String symp_name;
private String symp_part;

public UserData(String sid, String symp_name, String symp_part){
    this.sid = sid;
    this.symp_name = symp_name;
    this.symp_part = symp_part;
}

public String getSid() {
    return sid;
}
public String getSymp_name() {
    return symp_name;
}
public String getSymp_part() {
    return symp_part;
}
```

After requesting the JSON object, I use `userDataList.add(data)`, to stored the data in array.

Now I would like to display symp_name into android setMultipleChoiceItem. I notice that setMultipleChoiceItem accept CharSequence as its parameter. So I have no idea on how to convert the symp_name into char sequence.
I try to use this code:

```
ArrayList<UserData> spart = MainActivity.userDataList;
UserData symp = spart.get(spart.size());
CharSequence[] symptom = symp.getSymp_name();
```

Unfortunately, it does not working. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ArrayList<UserData> spart = MainActivity.userDataList;
UserData symp = spart.get(spart.size());// it will return a single object
```

`CharSequence[] symptom = symp.getSymp_name(); // this will return a single name which you are trying to feed into Array.`

You can create a Char array while traversing spart arraylist

`CharSequence[] symtoms= new CharSequence[spart.size()]
    for(int i =0;i<spart.size();i++){
            charSequences[i]= spart.get(i). getSymp_name();
        }`

And now set this charSequence to alertDialog using setMultichoice call.
Hope this resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Visit [How to convert a String to CharSequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391970/how-to-convert-a-string-to-charsequence) 
This question can let you know how to convert the symp_name into char sequence.
If your problem still wasn't solved.I suggest you can debug your project to see variable "symp" is correct or not