# Java: Inheritence of static methods on example commons-lang3 `StringUtils`

Tags: java, inheritance, apache-commons-lang3

I want to build upon `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils` and add a certain method specific for a problem of mine. So I try to inherit from the commons class and write

```
package org.test.project;

public class StringUtils extends org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils {

    public static boolean myMethod(final String cs) {
        // My method body
    }

}
```

Now, I want to use the method `public static boolean isEmpty(final CharSequence cs)` from `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils` in another part of my code. As I recall and [from this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1391976/3154817) a `String` is a `CharSequence`. Thus, I write

```
package org.test.project.package;

import org.test.project.StringUtils;

public class TestClass{

    public void someMethod(String s){

        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(s)){
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Why do I get the error:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol: method isEmpty(String)
location: class StringUtils
```

in my IDE?

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10292034) I have the info that "All methods that are accessible are inherited by subclasses." Therein, it is also stated

> The only difference with inherited static (class) methods and inherited non-static (instance) methods is that when you write a new static method with the same signature, the old static method is just hidden, not overridden.

But I do not have a method `isEmpty` with the same erasure.

---

### Edit

So, thanks to @luksch, I added a method

```
public static boolean isEmpty(final String cs) {
    return isEmpty((CharSequence)cs);
}
```

in my `StringUtils` class and that works. However, for testing I want to call `public static String center(final String str, final int size)` from the commons library. So I write

```
package org.test.project.package;

import org.test.project.StringUtils;

public class TestClass{

    public void someMethod(String s){

        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(s)){
            // do stuff
        }

        String test = StringUtils.center("test",10);

    }
}
```

I do not have any kind of method `center` my `StringUtils` subclass. So I thought, it would just automatically call the method from `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils`. However, I get the equivalent error message as above:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol: method center(String,int)
location: class StringUtils
```

Why?

Comment: does it work when you cast to ```CharSequence``` in your call of ```isEmpty``` inside ```someMethod```?

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work.

Comment: You don't need to `extend` from StringUtils. In fact, that will probably end up confusing things. The preferred method is to call the static methods directly (you can use static imports if you need them a lot).

Comment: (but what you are doing should work... )

Comment: Thanks, I know that I don't have to extend from commons-lang `StringUtils`. However, I do have classes that use method from my `StringUtils` and commons-lang `StringUtils` extensively, and I do not always want to write the full class name for the sake of clearness. That is where my question arises from.

Comment: Ok, everything works. It was just a matter of updating a dependency in my code as my `StringUtils` is in another project.